# Data Application based on OO Concepts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, design-patterns, oop

I'm looking for an application developed in C# with following qualities, which is available as source code.

1. Based on OO Architecture
2. Must connect to DB.
3. Must handle atleast a "one to many master child" relationship (eg: Order and items ordered)
4. Should display the data using Datagrid or other similar controls.
5. Reports (either with report viewer or otherwise)

I want to understand the layering of objects better.  Could you please help by providing some links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic. Try code project or some good books:

http://www.codeproject.com/

Comment: What books you suggest... I found books that teach the basic oo principles (like inheritance)...  I'm looking for building APP on OO principles...

Comment: @King Look up design patterns, check also codeplex, and you can also check out various enterprise frameworks but that's probably more then you need. Pro C# and .Net is best book on .NET, not sure the exact title. Solid black cover only! Quite a few books with similar names.

Comment: Thanks Curtis... I found this link useful.. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/AdoNetForOopPart2.aspx